# To View ProfilePicture in Xcode of facebook user

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, interface-builder

When i am using

```
self.profilePic.profileID = user.id;
```

i end up with this error

```
-[UIView setProfileID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x69626f0
2012-09-11 09:49:50.535 TweetApp[992:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setProfileID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x69626f0'
```

can anyone help on this topic??

Comment: +1 but I really wanted to downvote your question just because u have accepted a wrong solution.

Comment: Hmmmm, Nice idea that you asked, because I don't need to ask and wait. So from my point - only upvote! =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are talking about Facebook Scrumptious sample project. If that is the case, you have to set the Class of UIView control to `FBProfilePictureView`

[image]

Comment: Then there can be another issue. Checkout the following page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/personalize/ and see the last line of code [FBProfilePictureView class];. Maybe you are missing that.

Answer (score 28):

You can fix this issue simply. Just put this line code `[FBProfilePictureView class];` at the first line of method application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [FBProfilePictureView class];
    //...
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I am facing that problem too. :D

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, itsaboutcode is right. Call [FBProfilePictureView class]; in your AppDelegate and the problem will be fix

++

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it step-by-step.

`self.profilePic` refers to your property of `UIView` type.

Then you are trying to set this property's property `profileID`, but `UIView` class doesn't have such and you get the exception.

It will be easy for you to understand in the future from the error message, pay attention to the reason:

> '-[UIView setProfileID:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x69626f0'

It tells you the method `-setProfileID:` is called for `UIView*` object and with the code you posted it is clear why it happens.

I suppose you have `profileID` property in the view controller, then you'll want to use

```
self.profileID = user.id;
```

Or if `self.profilePic` should support `profileID` property then you initialized it incorrectly, find the initialization place to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem make sure your profile pic is an instance of FBProfilePictureView go to your layout and change the class of your view to be FBProfilePictureView notice your fb profile pic is a UIView not an ImageView that means u need to add view and change its class to FBProfilePictureView not an ImageView

also add this line at the first of your app delegate  [FBProfilePictureView class];
[image]

[image]