# Facebook SDK login for xcode crashes on getting avater

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm doing this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0).

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362740/to-view-profilepicture-in-xcode-of-facebook-user) but doesn't work

**MyViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBProfilePictureView *profilePictureView;
```

**MyViewController.m**

```
@synthesize profilePictureView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self loginToFacebook];
}

-(void) loginToFacebook {

    FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]];
    loginView.frame = CGRectOffset(loginView.frame, (self.view.center.x - (loginView.frame.size.width / 2)), 380);
    [self.view addSubview:loginView];
    loginView.delegate = self;
}

#pragma mark - Delegates

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {      
    self.profilePictureView.profileID = user.id;
}
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    // Call FBAppCall's handleOpenURL:sourceApplication to handle Facebook app responses
    BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

    // You can add your app-specific url handling code here if needed

    return wasHandled;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [FBProfilePictureView class];
    return YES;
}
```

2014-05-15 20:13:41.996 Wobbly[6231:60b] -[UIImageView setProfileID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d60a20

2014-05-15 20:13:41.998 Wobbly[6231:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setProfileID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d60a20'

**Update: 31 may. It still doesn't work. I don't know the answer.**

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
profilePictureView.profileID = user.objectID;
```

"`profilePictureView`" there is a UIImageView object.  It knows nothing about what a "`profileID`" is.

The tutorial refers to "`self.profilePictureView.profileID`", which means that it's 1) a property and 2) it's a custom subclass of UIImageView.

So make certain you've defined your property this way:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBProfilePictureView *profilePictureView;
```

like as in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to call its `+class` method before it gets loaded in the view controller:

`[FBProfilePictureView class];`

That'll let you set the `-profileID`. One technique inside of the View Controller holding the `FBProfilePictureView`, do the following:

```
+ (void)initialize {
    [super initialize];
    [FBLoginView class];
    [FBProfilePictureView class];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem 
make sure your profile pic is an instance of FBProfilePictureView
go to your layout and change the class of your view to be FBProfilePictureView
notice your fb profile pic is a UIView not an ImageView that means u need to add view and change its class to  FBProfilePictureView not an ImageView

also add this line at the first of your app delegate
 `[FBProfilePictureView class];`

[image]

[image]